# Cannot get Homebrew Apache Setup to work in Catalina, PHP errors

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, macos-catalina

My brew doctor and apache config both said "ready to brew" or Synax OK. Installed via Catalina and for some reason I still only see the directory @ localhost and then I still get PHP errors when trying to connect to my Sites/mysite pages.

I have linked PHP correctly, I have no clue why it is still showing the directory only and giving me errors when trying to access my site:

Has these PHP errors like:

> PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header(), and something about Slack trace? This was within the actual site folder when trying to open index.php? There are no errors for homebrew or apache.

Its almost like it hates my php@7.4 update and will not connect because of that? But everything is linked properly, driving me nuts because this setup outside my work network is easy as pie.

It used to be at php@7.2 on a previous machine and wondering if going back to that may fix the Sites issue with it?

Makes absolutely no sense. If anyone has run into issues with only seeing their directory and then getting php errors please let me know! Cannot use my work computer because of this, and not sure how to do a vanilla apache install after homebrew messes with all of it and unloads it.

also seems to have issues installing a proxy for Grunt and even using grunt...

Good times.